# Unable to determine password age with in a script using Powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell-4.0

Good morning

I am having an issue when trying to determine the age of an AD user's password.

When running the following script section:

```html
#Check for Fine Grained Passwords
            $PasswordPol = (Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy $user)
            
            if (($PasswordPol) -ne $null)
            {
                
                $maxPasswordAge = ($PasswordPol).MaxPasswordAge
            }
            
            $expireson = $passwordsetdate.AddDays($maxPasswordAge)
            $today = (Get-Date)
        
            
            #Gets the count on how many days until the password expires and stores it in the $daystoexpire var
            $daystoexpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson).Days
        }
    }
    
    else
    {
        
        $daystoexpire = "N/A"
    }
    
    if (($User.Enabled -eq $True) -and ($AttVar.LastLogon -lt ((Get-Date).AddDays(- $Days))) -and ($User.LastLogon -ne $NULL))
    {
        
        $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
            
            'Name' = $User.Name
            'UserPrincipalName' = $User.UserPrincipalName
            'Enabled' = $AttVar.Enabled
            'Protected from Deletion' = $User.ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion
            'Last Logon' = $AttVar.lastlogon
            'Password Never Expires' = $AttVar.PasswordNeverExpires
            'Days Until Password Expires' = $daystoexpire
        }
        
        $userphaventloggedonrecentlytable.Add($obj)
    }
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```html
Cannot convert argument "value", with value: "30.00:00:00", for "AddDays" to type "System.Double": "Cannot convert the "30.00:00:00" value of type 
"System.TimeSpan" to type "System.Double"."
At C:\Users\t1-82042450\Desktop\PSHTML-AD.ps1:948 char:4
+             $expireson = $passwordsetdate.AddDays($maxPasswordAge)
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Any help on this one will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract the days out of the timespan, this should do the trick.

```
$passwordsetdate.AddDays(([timespan]$maxPasswordAge).totaldays)
```

Comment: Great! Please consider accepting it as the answer for the benefit of future readers